# Clearing timeout for ajax query

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm building a Drop-Down menu with AJAX, and I want to delay the user query for 3 seconds before actually submitting it.

So I tried something like this:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(startcounting);
    var startcounting = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get( "mailing_search.php", { query: $("#searchitem").val() } ).done(function( data ) {
                console.log("Query Submitted");
                $("#searchbox").html(data);
            });     
        },3000);
    }
});
```

This doesn't work. it won't clear the timeout.
Lets say I input "samsung" it runs the query 7 times.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: startcounting is undefined due to javascript hoisting property

Comment: So is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the variable scope. You must declare `startcounting` outside your function.

```
var startcounting;
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(startcounting);
    startcounting = setTimeout(function() {
        $.get( "mailing_search.php", { query: $("#searchitem").val() } ).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("Query Submitted");
            $("#searchbox").html(data);
        });     
    },3000);
}
```

});

Comment: Polluting the global scope for such simple operation is _very_ bad .

Comment: What do you mean? its just one variable

Comment: @NirTzezana That's not the point. read my second answer. I attached references. try to avoid global variables. youll never know who might change them.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing it : http://jsbin.com/eqUvAYe/5/edit

You are looking for function debouncing.

```
function debounce(el)
{
    var exec;

  $(el).keyup(
  function ( )
    {
        if (exec)
        {
            clearTimeout(exec);
        }
        exec = setTimeout(function ()
        {
           console.log('1');     // put your ajax call here
        }, 3000);
    });

}

debounce($("#search"));
```

or (without wrapper function )

```
$("#search").keyup(
    function ()
    {
        var startcounting;
        return function ()
        {
            if (startcounting) clearTimeout(startcounting);
              startcounting = setTimeout(function ()
            {
                console.log('1') //put your ajax here.
            }, 3000);
        }
    }()
);
```

After reading (again ) your question , this is what you need. no need to put global variables.

FYI :

there are 2 ways for such operations :

1) throttle functions

2) function debounc.

After reading the book : [Third party javascript](http://dl.e-book-free.com/2013/07/third-party_javascript.pdf) :

there is a section there about :

> Controlling expensive calls: throttle and debounce The solution to
>   this problem lies in two techniques designed to control how often your
>   functions are called. These techniques—throttle and debounce—work by
>   creating a wrapper function that rate-limits calls to the original
>   function

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try the following. declare the timer function outside of keyup.

```
startcounting = setTimeout(function() {
        $.get( "mailing_search.php", { query: $("#searchitem").val() } ).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("Query Submitted");
            $("#searchbox").html(data);
        });     
    },3000);
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(startcounting);

}
```